# Firestore React typescript how to read nested regions or group cities by regions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

Could you help me to extract regions from all cities uniquely like image. And how can I group cities by regions.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I need to show in some like cities under each region

Comment: Can you show some code of what you tried this far ?

Comment: Please include the code you've attempted. Also, it’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)